# C# 8 validate arguments with utility method

Tags: c#, nullable, c#-8.0, nullable-reference-types

Say I have a method that accepts a [nullable reference type](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/nullable-references) like:

```cs
int Func(string? param)
{
    return param.Length;
}
```

The compiler correctly warns that `param` should be checked for `null`.

Before C# 8, I was used to validating arguments with external utility functions like this:

```cs
public static class Validate
{
   public static void NotNull(object? value, string parameterName, string? field = null)
   {
     if (value == null) throw new ArgumentNullException(parameterName + (field == null ? string.Empty : "." + field));
   }
}
… 
int Func(string? param)
{
    Validate.NotNull(param, nameof(param));
    return param.Length;
}
```

In this case, it seems that the compiler can't detect that argument `param` is actually checked for `null` inside of the `Validate` method, and thus still complains.

Is there no other way to directly test for `null` values inside of the method?

```cs
int Func(string? param)
{
    if (value == null) throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(param));
    return param.Length;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use [`[NotNull]`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.codeanalysis.notnullattribute) for this, so the compiler learns that after calling `Validate.NotNull` the value is never `null`.

```
using System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis;

public static class Validate
{
   public static void NotNull([NotNull]object? value, string parameterName, string? field = null)
   {
     if (value == null) throw new ArgumentNullException(parameterName + (field == null ? string.Empty : "." + field));
   }
}
```

Result: this won't give warnings anymore:

```
int Func(string? param)
{
    Validate.NotNull(param, nameof(param));
    return param.Length;
}
```

### Side note - signature of Func method

Of course the question is why the Func method doesn't have the signature:

```
int Func(string param) // no null allowed
```

If that isn't possible, you could also use another attribute [`[DisallowNull]`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.codeanalysis.disallownullattribute), so

```
int Func([DisallowNull] string? param) // gives warning if called with null compile time
```

### Side note - more attributes

There are more awesome attributes

[image]

Check [Microsoft docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.codeanalysis?view=netcore-3.0)

Comment: It's worth also noting that if you're using Microsoft Code Analysis (e.g., [`Microsoft.CodeAnalysis`](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.CodeAnalysis)), and you're storing your reusable guard methods in an external library, then you'll additionally need to annotate your parameters with `[ValidatedNotNull]` to satisfy its validation checks. Code Analysis is able to detect this for local methods, but not for external classes; as such, it requires the additional hint. This may be resolved in a future release, once Code Analysis is updated to be fully aware of C#'s nullability context.

Answer (score 1):

A method I use a lot that sounds like what you're looking for is something like this:

```
public static T MaybeThrow<T>(
   this T? pObject,
   string? pMaybeErrorMessage = null
) where T : class {
   if (pObject == null)
      throw new ShouldNotBeNullException(pMaybeErrorMessage);

   return pObject;
}
```

Used something like this:

```
int Func(string? param) =>
   param
   .MaybeThrow(nameof(param) + " was null")
   .Length;
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's my take :)

```
int Func(string? param)
{
        return param?.Length ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(param));
}
```